# my minecraft skin was working okay........except for the torso

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a custom skin, uploaded it, and everything loaded but the torso. The torso is black just black; even though the shirt i made was neon. I covered everything in the outer layer but i forgot about the body.....i didn't think the body was important so i skipped it.. and if i should have then should i make the skin again or does it not matter and i just have to fill it in? help me please.....

Comment: Of course you need the entire thing, the game can't just read your mind about what you want the torso to look like.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

Did you have transparency of any sort? If so, that’s probably why it’s black.

Btw, the image with the yellow is supposed to demonstrate semi transparency.